# simplexml failed to parse xml like this?

Tags: php, xml

Is there a stronger reference?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:nutch="http://www.nutch.org/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns
:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" version="2.0">

    <channel>

        <title>Nutch: "php Developers" notdirectory:1 </title>

        <description>Nutch search results for query: "php Developers" notdirectory:1 </description>

        <opensearch:totalResults>2</opensearch:totalResults>
        <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
        <opensearch:results>2</opensearch:results>
        <opensearch:itemsPerPage>10</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
        <item>
            <title/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: It is always a good practice when you get something to fail to specify how it failed. Did you get an error? What was the error message? Did you get a different result than what you expected? Then what was that you expected and what did you get? Etc.
As noted by the two answers you got already your document does not have anything wrong except the line break in the middle of the namespace declaration, if you correct that the document is wellformed, otherwise it is not welformed, that means it is not XML.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a valid XML file.

> Empty prefix is not allowed according
>   to XML Namespace specification.
>
> Namespace prefix ':' is not defined.

Once I cleaned up the `opensearch` namespace definition (removed the excess quotation marks and line breaks) all looked good:

```
xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your exact code, it might have something to do with the linebreak on the first line

change it so that `xmlns` is right beside `:opensearch`

```
<rss
    xmlns:nutch="http://www.nutch.org/opensearchrss/1.0/"
    xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
    version="2.0"
>
```